# How to assign costs for turns on GRASS vector network analysis?

Tags: grass-gis, network, cost-path, shortest-path

I would like to get a better understanding of how to assign costs for turns when creating a least-cost path with GRASS network tools, basically because I don't want any line to be used twice for creating the path.

For example with [v.net.path](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.net.path.html), there exists the option to assign turning costs to each line with *arc_backward_column* and *turn_layer*.

**Question 1:** What's the difference between those two?

Then, I question whether any of them would be helpful, because in the [wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_network_analysis) it is mentioned that 'Vector directions are defined by the digitizing direction (a-->--b).' However, I do not want to define a direction in according to how lines are digitized (my lines are not), but in terms of the direction that the network graph has already used that line.

**Question 2:** What is used as direction if the layer is not digitized? Is there a way to consider the direction to the one that the network graph has already used that line for generating a least-cost path?